# Unable to create Seek Bar start & end point like this

Tags: android, xml

In my application I've customized `SeekBar` .But unable to change Both end style .

I want to create like this [for both end][image]

**Here is my XML CODE**:

```
<com.example.androidtesting.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/verticalSeekbar"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:progress="5" 
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>
```

Here is progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line">
<stroke android:width="12dp" android:color="#33CCFF" />
</shape>
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: try using this tool http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Comment: use a 9 patch drawable

Comment: do you want both side rounded corner right ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="line" >
   <corners 
        android:radius="100dp"/>
   <solid
    android:color="#3E9EDE"/>
   <size
    android:width="250dp"
    android:height="25dp"/>
 </shape>
```